# Requesting tag for Conceptnet

Tags: feature-request, support

Could you create a tag for conceptnet (http://conceptnet.io/). It would help with conceptnet related questions.

Thanks.

Comment: out of curiosity, do we have any conceptnet questions currently?

Comment: i didnt find any.. but i would like to tag my quesstion (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54053/conceptnet-api-documentation-for-wn-part-of-the-uri)

Comment: this seems a narrow use case and since there are no other questions related to the topic there doesn't seem to be a need currently.. when you have enough reputation you can always create new tags yourself